# Multiple controllers for a single RGBW circuit

Tags: led, led-strip, led-driver

I currently have an installation that consists of (1) wall mounted touch screen LED controller which controls a circuit of (4) RGBW LED strips.  What i'd like to do is add another WiFi based controller to the circuit.  Both controllers are PWM output.  I've considered the option of terminating all the wires together and using diodes on each leg to prevent back-flow into the other controller, but i want to make sure that is on the right track.  Thanks for any insight.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffuKhg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on how the controllers work.

If they are current regulated drivers then having them both on at the same time could burn out your LEDs.

If they are both simply voltage drivers with PWM for brightness, then you need diodes from both ends of each line.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn9gqC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>